# Yii2 Junction relation

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to get all the groups that are not joint by an user throught another table. My tables are user, user_to_usergroup and usergroup.

Is there a way to get the opposite results from a query?

The code is as follows:

```
public function getGroupsNotJoint() {    
return $this- >hasMany(Usergroup::className(), 
['id' => 'group_id'])->viaTable('user_to_usergroup', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

This code returns all the groups that a user belong, I just want the groups that the user doesn't belong.

Answer (score 1):

Name existing relation `getGroups()`, you can get the rest of the groups for current user by modifying this relation (applying additional condition):

```
public function getOtherGroups()
{
    return $this->getGroups()->andWhere(['!=', 'user_id', \Yii::$app->user->id]);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if in table user_to_usergroup I have joint a group but exists another row with same group_id but different user_id, it will return this row as "OtherGroup", and this group as not joint. 

I want to take all the groups I haven't joint, not all the rows I don't have my id...